# How to create an user editable radio button and then allowing to select the correct Option?

Tags: javascript, html

**In my case I am trying to make a panel for admin where admin can create Multiple Choice Based Question and can add options dynamically.
Here I am trying to make a dynamic radio button where the admin can create the option and then select the correct answer from the created options.
Can any one suggest a way how to achieve it ?**

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to pass the admin input to a database using php, otherwise if you want to use only js a good way will be to pass the choices into an array and store them in cookies.